# junit integration test spring property not resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit4

I have a simple intergration test that looks like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyIntTestConfig.class, properties = {some.property.key=value})
public class MyIntTest {
    @Autowired
    public MyComponent myComponent;

    // ...

}

@Configuration
public class MyIntTestConfig {
    @MockBean
    private MyComponent myComponent;
    @Bean
    public myComponent() {
        // ...
        return myComponent;
    }
}
```

In the `application.yml` there is

```
some:
  property:
    key: ${PLACEHOLDER}
```

When I run this test with `mvn clean test` I get the error

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'PLACEHOLDER' in value "${PLACEHOLDER}"
```

Many other answers suggest adding an `application-test.yml` and calling it a day but I want to do it directly on the test class as the parameter can change from one test class to another and I don't really want lots of different `.yml` test configuration files.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

**EDIT**

Deadpool's answer fixed the issue as it sets the actual placeholder, so in a case where a bunch of different property keys could have values derived from the same placeholder, his answer is the way to go. Setting each `some.property.key=PLACEHOLDER` works too, until you forget one, which is what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have placeholder for properties in `application.yml`

```
some:
 property:
  key: ${PLACEHOLDER}
```

You should use that placeholder to replace the value

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyIntTestConfig.class, properties = {PLACEHOLDER=value})
 public class MyIntTest {

    @Autowired
    public MyComponent myComponent;

      // ...

 }
```